# How do I add just the 'f' button, without the 'like' or 'send' button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

How do I add just the 'f' Facebook logo to my site, referring people to our Facebook page, without adding the words 'like' or 'send?'

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to just download the Facebook icon, place it in an image and have the image link to your Facebook page.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/yourpage">
<img src="http://www.editorsweblog.org/facebook-logo.png" style="border:none" />  Visit Our Facebook page</a>
```

Simple and it gets the job done.